# Merging audio file in android not working

Tags: android, audio, mp3, wav

I'm trying to merge/join two audio files.But the merged file contain only first file audio don't know what is the issue.I think the problem with headers.But don't know how to fix it.

e.g

f1=4kb

f2=3kb

finalFile=7 kb

Size shows merging done but don't know why audio is missed of second file.

Here is my code.

```
public static void meargeAudio(List<File> filesToMearge)
{


    while (filesToMearge.size()!=1){

        try {



            FileInputStream fistream1 = new FileInputStream(filesToMearge.get(0).getPath());  //(/storage/emulated/0/Audio Notes/1455194356500.mp3) first source file
            FileInputStream fistream2 = new FileInputStream(filesToMearge.get(1).getPath());//second source file

            SequenceInputStream sistream = new SequenceInputStream(fistream1, fistream2);
            FileOutputStream fostream = new FileOutputStream(AppConstrants.APP_FOLDER_PATH+"sss.mp3",true);
            int temp;

            while ((temp = sistream.read()) != -1) {
                // System.out.print( (char) temp ); // to print at DOS prompt
                fostream.write(temp);   // to write to file
            }


            fostream.close();
            sistream.close();
            fistream1.close();
            fistream2.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Help me if you can.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

mp4parser can use to append audio files

https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser/issues/155

use:

aspectjrt-1.7.3.jar

My Working Code:

```
public static void mergAudio(List<File> filesToMearge){


    try {
        while (filesToMearge.size()!=1) {

            String audio1 = filesToMearge.get(0).getPath();
            String audio2 = filesToMearge.get(1).getPath();


            // FileOutputStream fostream = new FileOutputStream(filesToMearge.get(0).getPath(),true);//destinationfile
            String outputVideo = filesToMearge.get(0).getPath();

            Movie[] inMovies = new Movie[]{
                    MovieCreator.build(audio1),
                    MovieCreator.build(audio2),
            };

            List<Track> audioTracks = new LinkedList<Track>();

            for (Movie m : inMovies) {
                for (Track t : m.getTracks()) {
                    if (t.getHandler().equals("soun")) {
                        audioTracks.add(t);
                    }
                }
            }


            File file1 = new File(filesToMearge.get(0).getPath());
            boolean deleted = file1.delete();
            File file2 = new File(filesToMearge.get(1).getPath());
            boolean deleted1 = file2.delete();


            Movie result = new Movie();

            if (audioTracks.size() > 0) {
                result.addTrack(new AppendTrack(audioTracks.toArray(new Track[audioTracks.size()])));
            }

            Container out = new DefaultMp4Builder().build(result);
            out.writeContainer(new FileOutputStream(outputVideo).getChannel());


            filesToMearge.add(0, new File(filesToMearge.get(0).getPath()));
            filesToMearge.remove(1);
            filesToMearge.remove(1);

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Not work:  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List com.coremedia.iso.boxes.MovieBox.getBoxes(java.lang.Class)' on a null object reference in "MovieCreator.build(audio1)". Audio files are mp3.

Answer (score 2):

You are right about header problem. Reason why your new audio file only recognized as first audio file because you directly concat both audio files. When MediaPlayer reads your merged audio header (bit rate, how long audio data, etc), it recognizes your first audio file only, because that is what it found first. To properly join 2 audio file, you need to read both their header and decode their audio data, recalculate new length of merged audio data and concat both uncompressed audio data, recompressed it (as MP3 for example) then write it to file.